# ‘virtual char std::ctype<wchar_t>::do_narrow(wchar_t, char) const’ is protected

Tags: c++, locale, facet

I'm trying to convert wstring to string with use of locale facets but I got stuck on following error:

```
test_facet.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test_facet.cpp:14: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘std::ctype<wchar_t>&’ from expression of type ‘const std::ctype<wchar_t>’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/locale_facets.h:1430: error: ‘virtual char std::ctype<wchar_t>::do_narrow(wchar_t, char) const’ is protected
test_facet.cpp:16: error: within this context
```

Source:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 locale loc("");
 std::wstring Str = L"ěščřžýáíé";
 std::string Str2;
 ctype<wchar_t> &ct = std::use_facet<std::ctype<wchar_t> >(loc);
 for(std::wstring::const_iterator It = Str.begin(); It < Str.end(); ++It)
   ct.do_narrow(*It, 'X' );
 std::cout << Str2 <<std::endl;
}
```

Could someone tell me, what I am dooing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 things:

1) `use_facet` returns reference to const, so you can't assign it to a non-const one. So declare ct as:

```
 const ctype<wchar_t> &ct = ....
```

2) As the second error message states, `do_narrow` is protected, making it unaccessible to external callers. Use `narrow`instead, which is public.

Comment: thanks for answer, somehow I missed all the public members of ctype and looked only on the protected ones :( silly me

Answer (score 0):

You cannot invoke do_narrow from this context. Only member methods of class ctype (and deriveds) are allowed to call do_narrow.